# How to change the edit form caption in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

[image]

How can i change the Caption "Edit Record" to "Edit Project Record"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `editCaption` or `addCaption` option of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#editgridrow). Default value of the options are defined in [grid.locale-en.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L28-L29)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically:

```
beforeShowForm: function (formid) {

var mytitle = "My text to show"; // or whatever you want

$(".ui-jqdialog-title","#edithd"+mygridid).html(mytitle);

}
```

As part of the setup:

```
editGridRow(id,{editCaption: 'Edit caption', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **addCaption** property to change caption of **addForm** and use **editCaption** property to change caption of **editForm**.

```
jQuery('#gridId').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pagerId',
{   //navbar options
            edit: true,
            editicon: 'fa fa-pencil blue',
            add: false,
            addicon: 'fa fa-plus-circle purple',
            del: false,
            delicon: 'fa fa-trash-o red',
            search: false,
            searchicon: 'fa fa-search orange',
            refresh: true,
            refreshicon: 'fa fa-refresh green',
            view: false,
            viewicon: 'fa fa-search-plus grey'
        },
        {
            editCaption:'Edit Project Record'
        }, //Edit
        {

        }, //Add
          {
addCaption:'Add Project Record'
          },
           {},
            {});
```